# C# DataReader issue when used with .AsInputStream() converted stream

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, datareader

I need to do various reads on a stream for a decryption process. (for WinRT project) For one, I'd like to do a ReadByte() to get the first byte of the stream. There-after I'd like to read a few bytes into an array, and then read the rest of the bytes into a buffer.

I open up a DataReader on a passed IInputStream object. Which in turn was created from a System.IO.Stream object using the .AsInputStream() method. When I look at the DataReader object during debugging I see that the UnconsumedBufferLength is 0, and I am unable to do ReadByte() or ReadBytes() lest I want to get a *"The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range"* exception.

Why does the DataReader object seem empty? I've had issues with the AsInputStream() method not returning an actual IInputStream before. How can I ultimately open a DataReader object on a System.IO.Stream object.

Code where the DataReader is assigned:

```
private Stream DecryptStream(IInputStream streamToDecrypt, byte[] key)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataReader = new DataReader(streamToDecrypt);

            int ivLength = dataReader.ReadByte();  //Throws exception (UnconsumedBufferLength = 0 remember)

            byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(iv);   //Throws exception (UnconsumedBufferLength = 0 remember)


            IBuffer toDecryptBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            toDecryptBuffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);   //Works, but only because toDecryptBuffer is of length 0. which is still useless.
```

Code that calls the above method:

```
Stream plainStream = DecryptStream(streamToDecrypt.AsInputStream(),key);
```

**Update: Code which created the stream**
This is where the stream is first created, from a System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive object. This is then passed to the interim Decryption funciton as "streamToDecrypt"

```
ZipArchiveEntry metaEntry = archive.Entries.Where(x => x.FullName == "myFullNameHere").FirstOrDefault();
Stream returnStream = metaEntry.Open();
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the first "streamToDecrypt"?  Is it a file, httpstream etc?

Comment: Added an update for you Jon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call datareader.LoadAsync(size) to load the file into the buffer before reading it.

Change your decrypt method to something like this:

```
private async Task<Stream> DecryptStream(IInputStream streamToDecrypt, byte[] key, int uncompressedSize)
{
    try
    {
        var dataReader = new DataReader(streamToDecrypt);
        await datareader.LoadAsync(uncompressedSize);

        int ivLength = dataReader.ReadByte();  //Throws exception (UnconsumedBufferLength = 0 remember)

        byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(iv);   //Throws exception (UnconsumedBufferLength = 0 remember)
```

Then when you call it, pass in the uncompressed size from the ZipArchiveEntry:

```
await DecryptStream(streamToDecrypt.AsInputStream(),key, streamToDecrypt.Length);
```